# Python - Tkinter - Label text from StringVar does not display

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple GUI calculator and the stringNumbers won't display on label. I had tried it and it worked before but I had to use a calculator late night and thought why not my py calculator and it served my ass this time. Can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I use a mac python3  from tkinter import *

```
from tkinter import *

def Button_press(num):

    global equation_text

    equation_text = equation_text + str(num)

    equation_label.set(equation_text)


def equals():

    global equation_text

    try:
        total = str(eval(equation_text))

        equation_label.set(total)

        equation_text = total

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        equation_label.set("Arithmetic error")

    except SyntaxError:
        equation_label.set("Syntax error")

def clear():

    global equation_text

    equation_label.set("")

    equation_text = ""


window = Tk()

window.title("Calculator")
window.geometry("500x500")

equation_text = ""

equation_label = StringVar()

label = Label(window, textvariable=equation_label, font=("consolas", 25), bg="white", height=3, width=22)
label.pack(pady=9)

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

button1 = Button(frame, text="1", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(1))
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

button2 = Button(frame, text="2", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(2))
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)

button3 = Button(frame, text="3", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(3))
button3.grid(row=0, column=2)

button4 = Button(frame, text="4", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(4))
button4.grid(row=1, column=0)

button5 = Button(frame, text="5", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(5))
button5.grid(row=1, column=1)

button6 = Button(frame, text="6", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(6))
button6.grid(row=1, column=2)

button7 = Button(frame, text="7", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(7))
button7.grid(row=2, column=0)

button8 = Button(frame, text="8", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(8))
button8.grid(row=2, column=1)

button9 = Button(frame, text="9", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(9))
button9.grid(row=2, column=2)

button0 = Button(frame, text="0", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press(0))
button0.grid(row=3, column=0)

plus = Button(frame, text="+", font=30, height=3, width=4,
              command=lambda: Button_press("+"))
plus.grid(row=0, column=3)

minus = Button(frame, text="-", font=30, height=3, width=4,
               command=lambda: Button_press("-"))
minus.grid(row=1, column=3)

multiply = Button(frame, text="*", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                  command=lambda: Button_press("*"))
multiply.grid(row=2, column=3)

divide = Button(frame, text="/", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                command=lambda: Button_press("/"))
divide.grid(row=3, column=3)

equal = Button(frame, text="=", font=30, height=3, width=4,
               command=equals)
equal.grid(row=3, column=2)

decimal = Button(frame, text=".", font=30, height=3, width=4,
                 command=lambda: Button_press("."))
decimal.grid(row=3, column=1)

erase = Button(window, text="clear", font=30, height=2, width=4,
               command=clear)
erase.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.  The usual reason for a Tk Var to not work is that you've called `Tk()` more than once; perhaps you had run the code in a Python session where you'd previously called `Tk()`?

Comment: Thank you so much. Just ran it after quitting the IDE some time ago and it worked. Guess that must have been it.